# How to solve performance and hot reload issues in flutter?

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, flutter-web, flutter-hotreload

I have come to know that flutter is much faster..But when I run it on web , it takes almost 4 minutes to start..How to reduce its launch time?
Again there is an awesome feature of flutter called hot reload.
But when I try to perform hot reload(both from VSCode and window powershell) it says

```
  `Performing hot restart...`
```

and restart the whole application which takes too much time..How to solve?

Comment: in the console which u are running flutter on (cmd or git terminal) u can restart by either 'r' or 'R'. the first one restarts faster than the second one.

Comment: I don't want to restart..I want hot reload..But unfortunately it performs hot restart instead of hot reload(even if I press 'r' or 'R')

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter Web "Hot Reload" is not available, that's why `r` and `R` will do the same thing and perform a "Hot Restart".

That being said, 4min is pretty much, does this only mean building time or your application to load? If it is the latter I would consider investing in some optimization work to speed up the loading time or check your systems specs.

Comment: Yes only to load
Btw what should I do in the hot reload issue?My pc doesn't support emulator or simulator